# Pre-load content into Documents or Library directories from XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building an iPhone app that requires preloaded content. This content is presented so that it tests the user's knowledge, but is not modified by the user. The content consists of proprietary image files and pdf files.

From what I understand, the best practice would be to store this in the app's Library or Documents directories (please inform if this assumption is not correct). In a future version of the app I might want to upload additional (not replacement) content via API, but this is not part of the initial version.

I have seen many posts and tutorials regarding obtaining paths to the Documents and Library directories of an app, and reading/writing to them. This is all good and useful, but not what I am looking for here.

I would like to preload the content into the Documents and/or Library directories, for the simulator initially, to test app in simulator; and ultimately to the release version. I would have thought this would be possible to do from XCode without writing code.

I have not been able to find a solution to this on Stack Overflow or other places on the net. Any pointers, links, solutions are welcome. I am using XCode 10.3 with Swift 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [File System Programming Guide: File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html), which shows us:

[image]

The “data container” (including the Documents and the various Library folders) is for content generated/saved by the app. When, in Xcode, you mark resources as being part of the target, that becomes part of the bundle, and your app can retrieve it from there at runtime.

Theoretically, yes, you could copy data from the bundle to the Documents and/or Library folders, but, yes, you would have do that programmatically. It seems a bit wasteful to have two copies of these resources on the device, but you can do whatever you want. Generally, though, resources included in the bundle would just be be opened directly from there at runtime, not copying it to the data container (except for those cases where you would need to change it, because bundle contents are read-only).

FYI, for additional information regarding the file system, see the [iOS Storage Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/204/) video.

Comment: Rob, Many thanks for your comments and links. I had been able to load content with the app bundle but would prefer to keep them separate, as in the Applications Support directory. From your response I now know that I cannot load to App Support Directory directly from XCode. I will have to rethink my content architecture. Again, thanks for the info.